# Need assistance regarding objective-c polymorphism and inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, polymorphism

**ClassA.h**

```
@interface classA

-(void)print1;
-(void)print2;

@end
```

**ClassA.m**

```
-(void)print1 {
    NSLog(@"I am class A 1");
}

-(void)print2 {
    NSLog(@"I am class A 2");
}
```

**ClassB.h**

```
@interface classB : classA

-(void)print1;

@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
-(void)print1 {
    NSLog(@"I am class B");
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
ClassA *a1 = [[ClassB alloc]init];
    [a1 print1];
    [a1 print2];
```

**Output**

```
I am class B
I am class A 2
```

**Error**

```
ClassB *a1 = [[ClassA alloc]init];
```

**Question**

`ClassB` is child of `ClassA` means `ClassB` has `ClassA` functionalities and its own also. But `ClassA` don't know that `ClassB` is its child.

So how `classA *a1 = [[classB alloc]init];` is working and giving the above output
and `classB *a1 = [[classA alloc]init];` is giving error

Comment: This is actually valid for most (maybe all) OOP languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[classB alloc]init]`
 - this is the part where you actually create the object, whereas
 `classA *a1`
 is only a declaration of, to put it simply, what will be "expected" from this object to be. Your classB is a subclass of classA, so it has everything classA has, and therefore won't cause errors when accessing properties or using methods.

On the other hand, when you create a classA instance and cast it to classB:
`classB *a1 = [[classA alloc]init]` 

the compiler will expect this object to do what classB is able to do, and since classB is a classA extension, it might cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of `classA *a1 = [[classB alloc]init];` is working because in objective-C, methods are resolved at run time. `[a1 print1]` sends a message to `a1` object which could be anything at the run time to invoke method `print1`. Even you can call `[a1 some_random_method]` where compiler will give warning but not error. Since, it is possible that in runtime, `some_random_method` can be added.

For the second case `classB *a1 = [[classA alloc]init];`, I think you get the error because of the concept that not all `classA` is  `classB`.

It is possible that `classB` has extra members and methods. By typecasting `classA` object to `classB`, you will try to access those extra members and methods which has undefined behaviour. So, compiler does not support implicit typecast from `classA` to `classB` and gives error.

However, you can explicitly typecast `classA` object to `classB`. In runtime, you can add methods which are special to `classB` to this object (objective-C supports adding methods in runtime) and call them.